# Создание объектов в цикле без использования массивов или списков

Tags: c#, массивы, list, циклы

Необходимо создать в цикле множество локальных объектов, которые сразу же освобождаются, то есть без использования массивов, списков и т.п.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Как вы понимаете `локальный объект` и `сразу же освобождаются`? И для чего вам это? Какую конечную задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Это просто тренировочные задания, чтобы посмотреть работу System.GC. Нужно создать переменную, затем создать эти объекты без сохранения, запустить процесс сборки мусора и проверить изменение поколения переменной.

Comment: Что есть локальный объект в данном случае -- сам не знаю точно, не мое задание. Но, думаю, в данном случае это можно заменить на обычный объект.

Comment: `foreach (var item in Enumerale.Range(0, 100).Select(x=>new MyObject(){})) { do something }` ?